# generic transaction/error handling with rxjava (mongodb)

Tags: java, mongodb, transactions, rx-java2

the reactive mongodb java driver comes with these methods to handle transactions:

```
MongoClient::   Publisher<ClientSession> startSession(); // to start a session
ClientSession:: Publisher<Void> commitTransaction(); // to commit the transaction
ClientSession:: Publisher<Void> abortTransaction(); // to abort the transaction
ClientSession:: void close(); // to close the session
```

I have tried to abstract these methods in Dao/Repository classes as far as possible:

```java
public Single<ClientSession> startTransaction();
public Function<T, SingleSource<? extends T>> commitTransaction(AtomicReference<ClientSession> sessionReference);
```

However, to make use of a transaction, I still need to do the following:

```java
AtomicReference<ClientSession> sessionReference = new AtomicReference<>();

someRepository.startTransaction() // open session & start transaction
            .flatMap(clientSession -> {
                sessionReference.set(clientSession);
                return someRepository.doStuff();
            }).flatMap(stuff -> someRepository.doMoreStuff())
            .flatMap(someRepository.commitTransaction(sessionReference)) // commit
            .doOnError(throwable -> sessionReference.get().abortTransaction()) // rollback
            .doFinally(() -> sessionReference.get().close()) // close session
            .subscribe();
```

Pretty much all of this is boilerplate code, which is identical for each method that starts and commits a transaction.

Is there a way to make this less redundant?

Like, would it be possible to extract the three invocations to commit/close/rollback the transaction into one reusable one?

Even better would be if it could also include the stuff to start and store the session/transaction, but I don't have a good idea to make this work in the reactive world (other than introducing a DTO which would always get passed through the whole chain).

Comment: You should be using the API described in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/.

Comment: The api described in the link you posted only shows examples for the sync java driver. I am using the reactive async java driver. Not sure what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: withTransaction performs retries on various conditions. Simply calling commit/abort means you wouldn't be handling write conflicts and other intermittent problems that would occur in a real deployment. I don't know what you specifically need to do to use the withTransaction API.

Comment: Yes, the docs mention this for the callback style api: `The new callback API also incorporates retry logic for TransientTransactionError or UnknownTransactionCommitResult commit errors.` I'll need to find out if this applies to the reactive driver. Didn't find anything in the docs. However, I think this question is mainly about reactive programming and not about the usage of the mongo driver. I have a flatMap, doOnError and doFinally and I would like to make that reusable - instead of copy pasting it everywhere.